# Python: I'm misunderstanding stack logic, but I'm not sure where

Tags: python, stack

I have a function that is evaluating an infix expression via use of stacks. (Bet you've never seen THIS one before.) It takes an expression in list format, wherein each item in the list is a single character (operand, operator, or parenthesis.)

```
s = Stack()
tempvar = None
ops = ['+','-','/','*']

for i in expression:
    if i == '('
        s.push(i)

    elif i.isdigit():
        if tempvar is None:
            tempvar = i
        else:
            tempvar = tempvar + i

    elif i in ops:
        if tempvar is not None:
            s.push(tempvar)
            tempvar = None

        popped = str(s.pop() + str(s.pop())
        last = s.pop()
        if last is not ')':
            popped += str(last)

        for x in popped:
            print 'Popping',x,'from the stack.'

        print 'Popping',last,'from the stack.'

        math = eval(popped)
        s.push(math)
        print 'Pushing',math,'back onto the stack.
```

My intention for using the "tempvar" string is that, since I'm iterating over the expression character by character, I will encounter an issue for multi-digit numbers. So I'm making a string out of them and pushing the string onto the stack instead.

I am having two problems with this, and I'm not sure why I'm getting one of them.

For input

```
((21*2)-(4/2))
```

I get output

```
Pushing ( onto the stack
Pushing ( onto the stack
Pushing 21 onto the stack
Pushing * onto the stack
Pushing 2 onto the stack
Popping 2 from the stack
**Popping * from the stack
Popping 2 from the stack
Popping 1 from the stack
Popping 21 from the stack**
```

I've set off the problem portion by asterisks. My understanding of stacks is that they function as last-in-first-out, and they don't care what is sitting on the top, pop takes it off. 21 was the first thing I pushed onto the stack, but it looks like it's getting read individually (as 21, the last entry to pop off) and split in half as '2' and '1'- but I would expect that the 1 would pop off before the 2! What am I misunderstanding about either stacks, or about what I've written?

Comment: What is `inStack` then? You don't define it.

Comment: An inconsistency in my naming when I typed this over here, which I've now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in popped:
    print 'Popping',x,'from the stack.'
```

`popped` is a string, so this loop will iterate over it one character at a time.

Comment: Duh... talk about looking for a problem in the wrong place. Thank you!